# Positioning tables inwithout default latex positioning mechanism

Tags: floats, positioning

Hi I am querying about some suggestions regarding latex table placement.
In m latex document I have an appendix section at the end of the paper. The appendix contains a couple of tables and a figure no text.
I placed mu bibliography before the appendix. That was ok, but the guidelines suggests that I need to place the appendix before the bibliography. I did so, moved the appendix section before bibliography.

But after that the default lace handling mechanism of latex is placing the tables and figures in the appendix in the midst of the references which is not desired. I just want them to appear after the references. How can I force that?

Comment: Issue `\clearpage` immediately *before* your bibliography.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Werner gives the correct solution.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/15925 for a comprehensive discussion of controlling placement of floating objects such as tables.